# Amazon S3 URL redirect to root /

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, routes

I have a static website on S3, and I want all the requests incoming to my-site.com/home/* redirect to my-site.com/*.

*(eg. my-site.com/home/etc.html -> my-site.com/etc.html)*

I've tried several ways to solve that, but there are only not so smart solutions. For an example I could write a redirection rule for all the html files like below.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>home/something.html</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>something.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

This works, but I don't want to create a rule for every new file.

`<ReplaceKeyWith>/</ReplaceKeyWith>` This method is also not working.

Is there a way to solve this problem or should I use nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `/home/{whatever}` to redirect to `/{whatever}` for all possible values of `{whatever}`, then you'll need a rule to match the key prefix `home/` and replace it with an empty string.

The `/` at the start of the path is not part of the key (or key prefix), so these expressions never begin with `/`.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>home/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I wonder why the official documentation doesn't mention that..

Comment: The example object keys [in general docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) and the keys and key prefixes shown in [conditional redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) are all missing a leading slash, but it's admittedly one of those things that isn't necessarily obvious unless you think about it in almost pedantic detail: the leading `/` symbolizes "the root" but isn't part of the actual name (key) of the object, and key *prefixes* are implicitly always left-anchored, by definition.